# VB scripts +  copy only files that has different modify date

Tags: vbscript

I Use the following VB script( Shell object ) to copy folders & files from  \server\kits_location To D:\ ,

We also get Displays of the Copying Files progress dialog as the folder is being copied.

**Source PATH - \\server\kits_location**

**Target PATH - D:\**

This VB script run every week in order to update files on the target drive "D:\"

Usually files on source (  \server\kits_location  ) not modified so in this case we not have difference between source files to target files

Because files are very big ( 1-10G)  ,

I want to copy only files that have different modify date

so only source files that has diff modify date from target files will copied to target drive ( D:\ )

Please advice what I need to add in my VB script in order to copy only the diff files from source to target

***my VB script***

```
     createobject("wscript.shell").popup "Start Copy FCO Kits from network server - \\server\kits_location\ to D:\ drive ", 2, "", 64 
     Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
     Const FOF_CREATEPROGRESSDLG = &H0&
     strPictureTargetDIR = "D:\" 
     Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace(strPictureTargetDIR) 
     ' Copy  Kits from network server to D:\ drive
     objFolder.CopyHere "\\server\kits_location\", FOF_CREATEPROGRESSDLG
     set objShell = Nothing
```

Comment: Can you use the `xcopy` command? It allows you to copy only those files that have different dates (whether greater or less).

Comment: can you provide example how to integrate xcopy in my code , Displays of the Copying Files progress dialog as the folder is being copied must be part of the proccess

Comment: Sorry, `xcopy` does not have a GUI, it is a windows command line utility. It does show you a list of files being copied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `XCOPY` like this to copy from a source to destination directory

Please change your paths to suit

I have used [these switches](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/289483)

- /f *Displays full source and destination file names while copying.*
- /d *copies all Source files that are newer than existing Destination files*
- /s *Copies folders and subfolders except for empty ones*.
- /e *Copies any subfolder, even if it is empty.*
- /y *Overwrites existing files without prompting you*
- /h *Copies hidden and system files.*
- /r *Overwrites read-only files*

  ```
  Dim Path1
  Dim Path2
  Path1 = "C:\temp\*.*"
  Path2 = "C:\test\"
  Call XcopyFiles(Path1, Path2)

  Sub XcopyFiles(strSource, strDestination)
      Dim wsh
      Set wsh = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
      wsh.Run "xcopy.exe """ & strSource & """ """ & strDestination & """ /f /d /s /e /y /h /r", 1, True
      Set wsh = Nothing
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: why xcopy not copy also the root directory - for example if the source is - \\server\kits_location , so I expect to copy the kits_location to D:\ , actually xcopy copied only dirs and files under kits_location directory