# VBScript to Compare 2 textfiles

Tags: date, vbscript, compare

I have two text files that I need to compare by date/time modified (not by its contents).
Source text file is at N:\folder1\source.log and the other is at C:\folder1\dest.log. If two text files are the same exit, if there not the same run N:\folder1\copy.bat

Basically, I have various files contained inside "folder1" in both locations in which i want the vbscript to only check the log file if the same. The batch file will simply copy and overwrite all files, making everything updated.

Comment: Please provide your code that you tried.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB scripts +  copy only files that has different modify date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681099/vb-scripts-copy-only-files-that-has-different-modify-date)

Comment: The copying part is already accomplished by the batch file. I only need the compare part in vbs. And only compare the two text files

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8xh895w(v=vs.84).aspx

Comment: How can I incorporate the path? This is my first attemp to vbs so i dont know much about it bear with me :)

Comment: so basically I need something like this (I just cant make it work somehow)

ASource = "C:\Documents and Settings\Source\Copy.txt"
BDest = "C:\Documents and Settings\Dest\Copy.txt"

If ASource = BDest Then
    Wscript.Echo "Same"
Else
    Wscript.Echo "Not Same"
End If

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z9ffy99%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) for file access, the .[DateLastModified](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ft05taf%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) property of the files to compare, and the [= (equal) operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hck4s70%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

```
>> t1 = goFS.GetFile("calibre.log").DateLastModified
>> t2 = goFS.GetFile("tmp\calibre.log").DateLastModified
>> WScript.Echo t1, t2, CStr(t1 = t2)
>>
05.09.2009 20:14:39 05.09.2009 20:14:39 True
```